# How to add List<int> to a DataContract of a web service

Tags: datacontract

I want to create a DataContract that is a class with 2 different List members. When I try to start the web service, I get the error that my method, SendEmail, is not supported by the Test WCF Client.
This is my Data Contract:

```
 [DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(int[]))]
public class EmailInfo
{
    private string strFromUserID = string.Empty;
    private string strFromAddress = string.Empty;
    private string strFromName = string.Empty;
    private object lstIndividualIDs = null;
    private object lstGroupIDs = null;
    private string strSubject = string.Empty;
    private string strMessage = string.Empty;

    [DataMember]
    public string FromUserID
    {
        get { return strFromUserID; }
        set { strFromUserID = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string FromAddress
    {
        get { return strFromAddress; }
        set { strFromAddress = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string FromName
    {
        get { return strFromName; }
        set { strFromName = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public object IndividualIDs
    {
        get { return lstIndividualIDs; }
        set { lstIndividualIDs = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public object GroupIDs
    {
        get { return lstGroupIDs; }
        set { lstGroupIDs = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Subject
    {
        get { return strSubject; }
        set { strSubject = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Message
    {
        get { return strMessage; }
        set { strMessage = value; }
    }
}
```

This is my method that uses the DataContract:

```
 public string SendEmail(EmailInfo emailInfo)
    {
        string tstrErrorMsg = string.Empty;
        SqlConnection SqlConn = null;
        try
        {
            return tstrErrorMsg;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (SqlConn != null)
            {
                SqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to have a DataMember in the DataContract that is of type List.  How do I add that type to a DataContract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the web service to run by changing the lstIndividualIDs and listGroupIDs to List.
I thought I had to use objects.
In case anybody else has this problem...

object lstIndividualIDs -> List listIndividualIDs 
same with GroupIDs.
This allowed the Test client to run the service..